# No matching provisioning profiles found (None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2, provisioning-profile

I am getting an error when archiving:

```
Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: com.apple.developer.in-app-payments.
```

I added apple pay capability since the last time I archived successfully, so it's probably to do with that. How do I add the entitlements to the provisioning profile? The whole certificates/provisioning profiles/app id concept is so confusing, wondering if there are any good reads (for dummies) on exactly what/why/how these work.

Comment: I see a Swift 2.X tag. It may be important... what versions of **both** Swift and Xcode are you working with?

Comment: I'm on XCode 7 and Swift 2.3

Comment: I can't help. There are some pretty major changes with Xcode 8. Since you have Swift 2.3, are you able to try Xcode 8? Last year you could use XC 7 and 8 in parallel....

Comment: I plan on moving to Swift 3 and Xcode 8 pretty soon. But I'm just about to submit to the AppStore so don't want to do it just yet. Once I submit, upgrading will be my next priority.

Comment: I frequent the Swift SO questions (it's a minor addiction) :-). There have been a few questions about issues with Xcode 7 and submitting to the App Store. That's the main reason behind my asking. I think you are on the right track - it's not Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to developer.apple.com and log in as your developer account. Go to the Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles section, and find the app ID for your app.  Click on it to expend the capabilities for the app ID.  Make sure In App Purchases is enabled for both development and distribution (more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2259/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009578-CH1-CERTIFICATES__IDENTIFIERS___PROFILES)).

[image: Apple developer app ID services screen]

Once you've made sure it is there, you'll want to re-generate the provisioning profile for the app ID, and then re-download the profile to your Mac.  I tend to remove all my old provisioning profiles when I do this, since having multiple profiles for the same application ID can sometimes confuse Xcode.  Provisioning profiles on your Mac are stored in `/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/`

After doing this, it isn't necessary, but I usually recommend devs to quit and relaunch Xcode.

As for resources, I think Apple's session, [What's New in Code Signing](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/401/), from WWDC 2016 was a great one for understanding the components that are required for code signing to work.

Answer (score 1):

> The whole certificates/provisioning profiles/app id concept is so confusing

Not only for you :). You don't have to add entitlements to your provisioning profiles. Try to go to apple developer website add your mac (if you didn't do it already) and generate new provisioning profile. After that download it and click 2 times (xCode should automatically add it to the project). If it doesnt solve the problem try to look into project structure code and change developer/project numbers manually to proper one.